# Laravel Livewire: How to check if all values in an array is False or True?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How to check if all values in an array is all false or true? So I have created a checkbox for **selecting students(wire:model="selectedStudents.{{ $stud->id }}").**

**The resulting array is like this [4 => true 5 => true 6 => false]** somehow i need to disable a function in my controller if all values is true or false. Please help me.

Comment: You can check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850452/check-if-multiple-values-are-all-false-or-all-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in_array php function should work.

```
in_array(true, $this->selectedStudents) {
    // all values are true
} else {
   // 1 + N are false
}
```

of course, always the array have items